# Jquery to change form action

Tags: jquery

I have two buttons in a form and two different pages have to be called when they are clicked. when button1 is clicked then page1 must be loaded and when button2 is clicked then page2 must be loaded. i know how to do this in  javascript but i have no clue about how to do this in jquery.Can any one help me?

Answer (score 237):

Try this:

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
   $('#formId').attr('action', 'page1');
});


$('#button2').click(function(){
   $('#formId').attr('action', 'page2');
});
```

Answer (score 35):

jQuery is just JavaScript, don't think very differently about it! Like you would do in 'normal' JS, you add an event listener to the buttons and change the action attribute of the form. In jQuery this looks something like:

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
   $('#your_form').attr('action', 'http://uri-for-button1.com');
});
```

This code is the same for the second button, you only need to change the id of your button and the URI where the form should be submitted to.

Answer (score 28):

Use `jQuery.attr()` in your click handler:

```
$("#myform").attr('action', 'page1.php');
```

Answer (score 22):

Please, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3863869/2096619

Quoting [Tamlyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132208/tamlyn):

> jQuery (1.4.2) gets confused if you have any form elements named "action". You can get around this by using the DOM attribute methods or simply avoid having form elements named "action".
>
> ```
> <form action="foo">
>   <button name="action" value="bar">Go</button>
> </form>
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>   $('form').attr('action', 'baz'); //this fails silently
>   $('form').get(0).setAttribute('action', 'baz'); //this works
> </script>
> ```

Answer (score 14):

For variety's sake:

```
var actions = {input1: "action1.php", input2: "action2.php"};
$("#input1, #input2").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("form").attr("action", actions[this.id]);
});
```

Answer (score 11):

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
$('#myform').prop('action', 'page1.php');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To change action value of form dynamically, you can try below code:

> below code is if you are opening some dailog box and inside that dailog box you have form and you want to change the action of it. I used Bootstrap dailog box and on opening of that dailog box I am assigning action value to the form.

```
$('#your-dailog-id').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var link = $(event.relatedTarget);// Link that triggered the modal
    var cURL= link.data('url');// Extract info from data-* attributes
    $("#delUserform").attr("action", cURL);
});
```

> If you are trying to change the form action on regular page, use below code

```
$("#yourElementId").change(function() { 
  var action = <generate_action>;
  $("#formId").attr("action", action);
});
```