# how change the link form action a accordance with the `<option>`?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, search-box

This form is search form. when I click the `<option>` "alfamart" or "bca", I want the link change.
like this, link: **/en2/maps(alfamart)or(bca)/** in accordance with the `<option>`
but how?

thanks

```html
<form action="/en2/maps".$id."/"><!--Relative url to the page that your map is on-->

    Distination: 
    <select name="textSearchTerms" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
        <option value="alfamart">Alfamart</option>
     <option value="BCA">BCA</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

<?php
$id = $_GET['textSearchTerms'];
?>
```

Comment: i dont see why you wanna do it because PHP will send the selected data anyway on the server and you can process with that.?

Comment: You should do this with JQuery, possible you need this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451600/jquery-to-change-form-action

Comment: Do you want to change the place where the action will be done i.e. the `action` attribute or you want to redirect the user who submitted the form to url that has the search term in it?

Comment: @jiff—yes, it's possible with any one of a dozen libraries. I'm sure the OP is aware of that.

Comment: Why not a listener on the select's change event? Then `this.form` gets the form, and `this.form.action` the *action* property to munge as you wish using `this.value` to get the value of the selected option. But why not just send the value of the select as form data and let the server work it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to get value from URL, you can change form action by select box value.

```js
$('.selectpicker').change(function(){
if($(this).val() == 'alfamart'){
 $('form').attr('action','alfamart.html');
  alert('action is alfamart.html');
} else {
 $('form').attr('action','BCA.html');
  alert('action is BCA.html');
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/en2/maps">

    Distination: 
    <select name="textSearchTerms" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
        <option value="alfamart">Alfamart</option>
       <option value="BCA">BCA</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```