# Is there any way of making a <select> go to url

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have this code below:

```
<select name='m-menu' onchange='location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'>
<option selected value='/users/lol'>My Account</option>
<option value='/?signout'>Sign Out</option>
<option value='/photos'>Photos</option>
<option value='/post'>Share/Post</option>
<option value='/feed'>Feed</option>
<option value='/chat'>Create Chat</option>
</select>
```

However I want it to go to the account if the user clicks on "My Account". Can this be done without adding an other `option` the the `select` tag, If so please help???

I will need this to be used for mobile browsers and I need this to go to the url if and when the user selects an option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML SELECT - Trigger JavaScript ONCHANGE event even when the option is not changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877527/html-select-trigger-javascript-onchange-event-even-when-the-option-is-not-chan)

Comment: would you like to see [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264051/how-change-the-link-form-action-a-accordance-with-the-option/35264310#35264310) ?

Comment: yes @pedram I would like to see it

Comment: Well it's what you want but with jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by changing the selected value when the user focuses on the select `onfocus="this.selectedIndex = -1"`.

```
<select name='m-menu' onfocus="this.selectedIndex = 0" onchange='location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'>
  <option value="" style="display: none">Select an Item</option>
  <option selected value='/users/lol'>My Account</option>
  <option value='/?signout'>Sign Out</option>
  <option value='/photos'>Photos</option>
  <option value='/post'>Share/Post</option>
  <option value='/feed'>Feed</option>
  <option value='/chat'>Create Chat</option>
</select>
```

I would also suggest you add your event listeners from a separate javascript file instead of using the on* attributes.
You can do that using `addEventListener`

Comment: Would there be any way of having it select an option when you click on it as it comes out blank???

Comment: It does not work on mobile browsers such as Safrai for IOS (It will not go to the first option if selected), Can this be fixed.