# How to change form action with jQuery based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-boot

Iam working on login page of my website. Using same login page the users and admin can login to website I have given two options(checkbox) based on than the form action should cange but it is not woking properly.
The form is This

```
<form method="post" id="loginForm">
    Username <input placeholder="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" type="text" required=""> 
        Password <input placeholder="Password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password" type="password">
        <input type="checkbox" id="user" checked="checked"> User 
        <input type="checkbox" id="adminAction"> Admin 
        <a href="#" class="text-right text-white text-capitalize">forgot password?</a>
         <input type="submit" value="Log In"> 
         <a href="/register" class="text-white  font-weight-bold"> Register Now</a>
</form>
```

And this is the jquery code

```
<script>
if($('#adminAction').is(':checked')){
        $('#loginForm').attr('action','/adminLogin');
    }
    else{
        $('#loginForm').attr('action','/userLogin');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure why you would need something like that. Its not a very good practice. You should use the same form and redirect the user accordingly AFTER he logs in  and has a specific role.Also this looks like a duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451600/jquery-to-change-form-action

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery to change form action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451600/jquery-to-change-form-action)

Comment: Thanks from your suggestion Dante R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dante mentioned, it's probably not a great idea to toggle between form actions on the client side. But all that aside, I think your issue is that you didn't put `$(document).ready` in your script. Furthermore, you should probably set an initial action in your form of `action='/userLogin'` since there's no action when the page initially loads, and there's no trigger in your code to change anything when the checkbox gets changed. Try something like this:

```
<form method="post" id="loginForm">
    Username <input action='/userLogin' placeholder="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" type="text" required=""> 
        Password <input placeholder="Password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password" type="password">
        <input type="checkbox" id="user" checked="checked"> User 
        <input type="checkbox" id="adminAction"> Admin 
        <a href="#" class="text-right text-white text-capitalize">forgot password?</a>
         <input type="submit" value="Log In"> 
         <a href="/register" class="text-white  font-weight-bold"> Register Now</a>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#adminAction').change(function(){
            var checked = $('#adminAction').is(':checked');
            if(checked){
                $('#loginForm').attr('action','/adminLogin');
            }
            else{
                $('#loginForm').attr('action','/userLogin');
            }
        })  
    });
</script>
```