# Using jquery to change form action URL

Tags: jquery, forms

I need to change the form action URL depending on the body class of the page. So far I have

```
$('document').ready(function () {
 if ($('body').hasClass('hosting')) {
      $('#quoteForm').attr('action', 'hostingURL');
      }
});
```

and that works perfectly. But I need to expand it to include more body classes. I tried

```
$('document').ready(function () {
 if ($('body').hasClass('hosting')) {
      $('#quoteForm').attr('action', 'hostingURL');
      }
 elseif ($('body').hasClass('workspace')) {
      $('#quoteForm').attr('action', 'workspaceURL');
      }
 else{}
});
```

but it isn't working. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: typo `elseif` a space between `else if`

Comment: Please try the answer here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979024/changing-the-action-of-a-form-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: You know people can just turn JavaScript off, right?

Comment: Only creeps turn off JavaScript

Answer (score 5):

add white space in `elseif` like `else if`